# using a value in a object that is in a array list to compare

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, string-comparison

i have an array list of a few objects which consist a set of a few different data type values
i want to know if i can take one of those values from all the objects in the array to use for comparison, normally i would do it like this

```
 objectname.getvariablevalue()
```

having the class containing a function that returns the variable i want like this

```
public getvariablevalue()
{
return variable;
}
```

however that would only get the variable for one object and I need the variable from all objects with out knowing what the names of every object, so i need something like

```
classname.getfirstvariablevalues;
```

or

```
objecttype.getallfirstvariablevalues;
```

also i should mention i should not use static functions or variables.

Comment: Instead of describing what you have, show us the code.

Comment: and what code you have doesn't compile

Comment: Well you have your objects in some kind of data structure, otherwise they wouldn't exist :P So just iterate over them and call on each one your getter method.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `List` or whatsoever with all objects and iterate over them calling the function and add the return into a different `List`?

If the objects have different types you can check them before you cast via `instanceof`